# Pyspark Dataframe: filter by row if it does not meet condition dependent on next column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Sorry if the title does not explain clearly, I could not think of a better way to phrase this. So I have a data frame that is organized as follows:

```
ID    Depart    Arrive  Time
****************************
A     1         2       1pm
A     2         3       2pm
A     4         1       5pm
```

So what I'm to do is find all the **Times** where one rows **Depart** does not match the next row's **Arrive**.
For example, the second column here has a **3** as it's **Arrive** but the third column has **4** as its **depart** (as opposed to 3).

What I'm hoping to get would be a new data frame with all these conditions. In the case of this data frame it would look like this:

```
ID    From    To      Time
********************************
A     3         4     [2pm,5pm]
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to do this with spark as opposed to converting the data frame into a different data structure and iterating over it. Apologies if I missed anything, I'm new to spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of Depart in the next row using `lead` and compare the the value of Arrive in the current row. If they are different, collect all the necessary information into a struct, and expand it later. Note that this solution only works for your time format (`ha`: hour followed by am/pm).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Time2')        

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Time2', 
    F.to_timestamp('Time', 'ha')
).withColumn(
    'unmatched_arrive', 
    F.when(
        F.lead('Depart').over(w) != F.col('Arrive'), 
        F.struct(
            F.col('Arrive').alias('From'), 
            F.lead('Depart').over(w).alias('To'), 
            F.array('Time', F.lead('Time').over(w)).alias('Time')
        )
    )
).dropna(subset=['unmatched_arrive']).dropDuplicates().select('ID', 'unmatched_arrive.*')

df2.show()
+---+----+---+----------+
|ID |From|To |Time      |
+---+----+---+----------+
|A  |3   |4  |[2pm, 5pm]|
+---+----+---+----------+
```